# Python Convert nested MutableMapping to nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary, loops

I have a nested MutableMapping that I wish to convert to a nested dictionary. When I say that I have a MutableMapping, I of course mean I have a class that inherits it. The structure sort of looks like:

```
'key': <myobject> where myobject is the MutableMapping with more nested myobject's
```

My current attempt at doing this has resulted in:

```
def __makeDict(c):
    c = dict(c)
    for item in c:
        if isinstance(c[item], MutableMapping):
            c[item] = Configuration.__makeDict(c[item])
            return c[item]
    return c
```

Feeding in the nested MutableMapping produces only the bottom most level of the tree (which I think I understand). The question is, how can I iterate over this and produce the correct result? Any input is appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def __makeDict(c):
    for item in c:
        if isinstance(c[item], MutableMapping):
            Configuration.__makeDict(c[item])
            c[item] = dict(c[item])

    return dict(c)
```

I figured it out. I re-arranged the order to use the mutating powers of `MutableList()` to help rebuild the dictionary.

Comment: I think you can just use `dict(some_mutable_mapping)`, will automatically take care of nested mappings.